# Does Entity Framework need associations on both sides?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ProductGroupId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup {get; set;}
}
```

What is the correct CodeFirst mapping where `ProductGroup` is required in `Product`?

And in the mapping, do I need to specify mapping for `ProductGroup`, or can I just set:

```
this.Property(t => t.ProductGroupId)
    .HasColumnName("productgroup_id")
    .IsRequired();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to map the relationship you want is this:

```
this.HasRequired(p=>p.ProductGroup).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.ProductGroupId);
```

I assume you are configuring this relation in a configuration class of the `Product` entity